# How to convert varchar to decimal when no row data exists

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a t-sql statement that sums up varchar values by converting them to decimals. If no values exist, to return 0.

The error I am receiving is "Error converting data type varchar to numeric". This occcurs only ***when no result data is returned***.

```
select sum(convert(decimal(28,8), isnull(myColumn, 0)))
from myTable
//...multiple inner joins
//...and multiple filter criteria
```

As no data exists the workaround I was thinking of was doing a select count to detect if any rows exist and then do the following statement. Are there any better solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All below answers do not work when NO DATA exists. Could not find any other way of doing other than doing a if exists.

This was part of a lot larger sql script and this specific part was updating a temp table.

```
if exists(select * from table inner join...where...)
being
    select sum(convert(decimal(28,8), isnull(myColumn, 0)))
    from myTable
    ...inner joins
    ...where clause
end
```

**Update**

The actual reason why it was erroring was because of the where clause where the conversion was happening, and erroring, on the joins before the where clause was being run. The inner joins were returning null values.

Comment: You might add an else statment to select 0 as firstcolumn, 0 as secondcolumn, so that you get a result set in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your isnull is in the wrong place.

```
sum(convert(decimal(28,8),isnull(myColumn,0)))
```

Convert the null value to 0 then convert to decimal and then finally sum.

Comment: Sorry I was writing the sql off the top of my head and wrote it wrong. The error still occurs when no rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(convert(decimal(28,8), isnull(myColumn,'0'))
```

Comment: I think that in this case You, have some invalid characters in that column and that why it fails, when no result data is returned this statement works. Look at the values looking for separation charaters or invalid decimal character that for some local can be ',' for other '.'. Where no data are found the select statement is not executed so in result you have only nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, some prefer COALESCE:

```
sum(convert(decimal(28,8), COALESCE(myColumn,'0'))
```

Comment: Could you run _select * from mytable_ and show us the first 20 rows?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query could help you

```
select isnull(sum(convert(decimal(28,8),isnull(myColumn,0))), 0)
from myTable
```